# How can I send data with custom load view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Normally we can send data to view with this method

```
$this->load->view('template',$data);
```

but now I used to use custom load view how can I send data on this method

```
$this->template->load('header','content');
```

Custom template for load view

```
class Template {
        var $template_data = array();

        function set($name, $value)
        {
            $this->template_data[$name] = $value;
        }

        function load($template = '', $view = '' , $view_data = array(), $return = FALSE)
        {               
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $this->set('contents', $this->CI->load->view($view, $view_data, TRUE));         
            return $this->CI->load->view($template, $this->template_data, $return);
        }
}
```

How can I send data with array (content , xxx(data))

Answer (score 0):

Within that `Template` class it is clear that the `load()` function takes `$view_data` as third parameter, so you simply send the data as the third parameter :

```
$this->template->load('header', 'content', $data);
```